# Contract call with ether and gas fails with revert

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, ganache

Testing with Truffle and solidity on localhost ganache network:

Works:

```
function dosomething(string a) {
    //do nothing
}
```

testing with:

```
TokenFactory tf = TokenFactory(TokenFactoryAddress);
function testDeployed() public {
  TokenFactory tf = TokenFactory(TokenFactoryAddress);
  tf.dosomething("lala"); //works!
  tf.dosomething.value(1000); //works!
  //assertions here
}
```

fails:

```
function dosomething(string a) payable {
   //do nothing
}
```

testing with:

```
TokenFactory tf = TokenFactory(TokenFactoryAddress);
function testDeployed() public {
  TokenFactory tf = TokenFactory(TokenFactoryAddress);
  tf.dosomething.value(100000)("lala"); //fails!
  tf.dosomething.value(100000).gas(1000000)("lala"); //fails!
  //assertions here
}
```

error:

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Comment: revert errors usually mean contract received bad input and `requre`/`assert` statements triggered the `REVERT` opcode. check what values your constructor is receiving

Comment: there is only one arg that is the same in the test and without payable it works perfectly. also i don't have any assert/requirement in the code. it must be something about how i send ether or gas problem but not sure what

Comment: either your contract doesn't have enough ether for that transaction or the gas that you are passing is not enough to create the contract.

Comment: I am passing 2M gas in the call and the first call where the contract is not payable executes with normal gas so it's not it I think. Also my contract has 20ETH which is more than enough. Does the TokenFactory contract also need ETH? I think not.

Comment: post constructor's code

Comment: I simplified the code so that the constructor does nothing..

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the TestContract according to the docs: https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-solidity#in-beta-testing-ether-transactions

there should be a line giving initial Ether to the contract:

```
 uint public initialBalance = 1 ether;
```